# Xcode 6 Beta 4 - Import swift class in the Test Target

Tags: testing, swift

I have downloaded Xcode6B4 and I encounter a problem that never happened on the beta 3. I defined several swift files with some extensions on basic swift types. When I want to call a method defined in theses files from the test target, the compiler does not find the definition of the method. Is that related to new keywords defining the access levels ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the release notes, all methods and properties are `internal` by default. The test target is a different module so anything you want to call from the test target must be declared as `public`.

Comment: Thank you.  I think that declaring things public is a step in the right direction for me, but I am still having trouble.  I'm getting compile-time errors that say that things from my project are not defined in the test code. Do I need to import something into the test code.  If so, how?